# Как присвоить родительскому блоку класс, если внутри него выбрана радиокнопка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, checkbox

Пробовал написать вот такую проверку (код ниже), на этом и остановился. Если бы получилось вывести хотя бы алерты, то дальше бы уже разобрался.

```js
if ($('form-radios input').checked) {
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert(0);
}
```

```css
label.option.art-radiobutton.art-checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  height: 15px;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
}
label.option.art-radiobutton {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit-attributes-field-tirag--12" class="form-radios">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-695--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-695--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="695" class="form-radio ajax-processed">1000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-700--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-700--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="700" checked="checked" class="form-radio ajax-processed">10000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-696--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-696--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="696" class="form-radio ajax-processed">2000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-697--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-697--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="697" class="form-radio ajax-processed">3000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-698--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-698--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="698" class="form-radio ajax-processed">4000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-693--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-693--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="693" class="form-radio ajax-processed">500</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-699--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-699--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="699" class="form-radio ajax-processed">5000</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.form-radio').change(function() {
    $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}

div.checked {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit-attributes-field-tirag--12" class="form-radios">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-695--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-695--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="695" class="form-radio ajax-processed">1000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-700--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-700--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="700" checked="checked" class="form-radio ajax-processed">10000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-696--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-696--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="696" class="form-radio ajax-processed">2000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-697--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-697--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="697" class="form-radio ajax-processed">3000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-698--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-698--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="698" class="form-radio ajax-processed">4000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-693--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-693--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="693" class="form-radio ajax-processed">500</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-field-tirag">
    <label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-tirag-699--12">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-tirag-699--12" name="attributes[field_tirag]" value="699" class="form-radio ajax-processed">5000</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-radio:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).closes('div').addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: да мне бы проверку не после того как выбрали, а после загрузки страницы, потому что когда страница загружается флаг уже стоит на определенным элементе.

Comment: Добавил к ответу проверку после загрузки.